# Which denomination do majority of contemporary Hindus adhere to?

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism, smriti, shaktism

I know more Vaishanvas and Shaivas exist in South India and Shaktas are more prominent in the east,But in North what are the major denominations of Hindus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hard numbers are available.  Only Vaishnavites seems to continue to exist as sects/subsects/sampradayas in significant numbers.  Other sects like Shaivism and Shaktism do not have large following any more.

Non-Sectarian worship of Rama, Krishna, Siva, Hanuman, Durga, Kali, Murugan, Ganesa, Iyappan et al has large following.  Sai Baba is also big.

In North India it would be Rama, Krishna, Siva (with their spouses) and Hanuman.

I assume the statistics below includes both sectarian and non-sectarian worshipers:

Wiki says

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishnavism

> According to a 2010 estimate by Johnson and Grim, the Vaishnavism tradition is the largest group with about 641 million or 67.6% of Hindus.[283] In contrast, Jones and Ryan estimate Vaishnavism to have perhaps 200 million followers, and it being the second largest tradition of Hinduism after Shaivism.

Comment: Isn't non-sectarianism a fundamental tenet of Smartha denomination.Also,Is advaita vedanta the dominant philosophy among Hindus?

Comment: Yes - Smartism is not a sect.  Smartas do not devalue any deity of Hinduism.  Some people say even vaishnavites are Smarta but that would stretch the definition too far.  Smartic Advaita I think is the modern face of HInduism.  The vast mass of Hindus do not have a philosophy - they observe a subset of lay practices - going to temples, pilgrimages, samskaras etc. @Rishx