# What proportion of Hindus are aware of Vedanta in their religious practice?

Tags: vedanta, practice

Hinduism as practiced today consists of temple worship of deities, Puja and Bhajans at home, going to pilgrimage sites, getting Samskaras conducted (most importantly - marriage ceremony and last rites). Hindus may attend pravachans on the Bhagavad Gita - but it is not presented as Vedanta, as far as I know.

Most Hindus would know when they are practicing Bhakti ot Tirtha-yatra etc.

Are there things lay Hindus do as part of their religion that they are aware are Vedantic?

Comment: How are we supposed to know whether one is aware of Vedanta or not? Should a survey be conducted ?

Comment: surveys ARE conducted https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32661/which-denomination-do-majority-of-contemporary-hindus-adhere-to/32666#32666  but one can aswer from one's experience and what contemporary popular teachers say in their discourses.